# why would a corn snake have flat looking skin on their sides almost looks like wings

Tags: health

[image]
why would a corn snake have flat looking skin on their sides almost looks like wings . It just looks like their is something wrong . Could it be she's pregnant ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the remains of a bad shed just from the quality of the picture.
What do you feed the snake and how often? Describe the setup of the snake. Do you house snakes together?

Comment: It was lose skin . She died a few days ago . She had a lump in her belly i was thinking maybe a parasite caused a blockage . She ate a fuzzy and a pinky just 2 weeks before . The skin on the side looked like maybe she lost allot of weight but that was weird because she just ate so like i said maybe she couldn't digest her food . the take is a 65 gal. and their were 2 male corns with her . the take is at 80 deg. . have the red light and white lite so idk .

Comment: looking for another female around a yr old if anyone knows where i can find one .

Comment: It's not good to house corn snakes together. It stresses out the snakes even if they do not physically show signs of aggression. This can lead to health problems. The other problem is egg binding. The males could try to mate with the female. If the female is too young the eggs will bind in her causing her to die.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear for your loss at any rate. If you're looking for a specific age I would recommend a breeder at a reptile expo. You can get a specific breed and type for relatively cheap depending on the breeder. Expos are held all the time just look up online. The other option is a pet store like Petco but they do not keep track of age.